# Free tools for decompiling SWF files?

Tags: gratis, open-source, decompiler

I'm looking for free tools to decompile and extract resources from SWF files for which I don't have a source anymore.

Open source tools would be beneficial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- [SWFTools](http://www.swftools.org/) - SWF manipulation and generation utilities

  You can install SWFTools distribution (which has also a command line program), and use [SWFExtract](http://www.swftools.org/swfextract.html), that can decompile flash files.

  On OSX, install via: `brew install swftools`.

  This will install tools such as: `as3compile`, `font2swf`, `jpeg2swf`, `pdf2swf`, `png2swf`,
  `swfbbox`, `swfc`, `swfcombine`,
  `swfdump`, `swfextract`, `swfrender`, `swfstrings`, `wav2swf`.

  `swfextracts` allows to extract swf movieclips and objects out of swf files.
- [FFDec](https://www.free-decompiler.com/) ([GitHub](https://github.com/jindrapetrik/jpexs-decompiler)) - JPEXS Free Flash Decompiler

  > Opensource flash SWF decompiler and editor. Extract resources, convert SWF to FLA, edit ActionScript, replace images, sounds, texts or fonts. Various output formats available. Works with Java on Windows, Linux or MacOS.

  Examples:

  ```
  java -jar ffdec.jar myfile.swf
  java -jar ffdec.jar -proxy
  java -jar ffdec.jar -proxy -P1234
  java -jar ffdec.jar -export script "C:\decompiled" myfile.swf
  java -jar ffdec.jar -selectclass com.example.MyClass,com.example.SecondClass -export script "C:\decompiled" myfile.swf
  java -jar ffdec.jar -format script:pcode -export script "C:\decompiled" myfile.swf
  java -jar ffdec.jar -format script:pcode,text:plain -export script,text,image "C:\decompiled" myfile.swf
  java -jar ffdec.jar -format fla:cs5.5 -export fla "C:\sources\myfile.fla" myfile.swf
  java -jar ffdec.jar -dumpSWF myfile.swf
  java -jar ffdec.jar -compress myfile.swf myfiledec.swf
  java -jar ffdec.jar -decompress myfiledec.swf myfile.swf
  java -jar ffdec.jar -onerror ignore -export script "C:\decompiled" myfile.swf
  java -jar ffdec.jar -onerror retry 5 -export script "C:\decompiled" myfile.swf
  java -jar ffdec.jar -config autoDeobfuscate=1,parallelSpeedUp=0 -export script "C:\decompiled" myfile.swf
  ```

  > Instead of "java -jar ffdec.jar" you can use ffdec.bat on Windows, ffdec.sh on Linux/MacOs

Comment: FFDec is awesome, even if it has a terrible GUI. A small remark regarding their DEB file: it can be made to run with OpenJDK rather than Oracle Java by changing the dependencies list.